# Overwriting the first N bytes in a file in Swift

Tags: swift, string, file, stream, overwrite

I'm trying to replace the first N bytes in a file in Swift with my own data, leaving the rest of the file unchanged, e.g. I have the string `"OOPS"`, the file (of any length) currently contains `Look, a daisy`, and I want it to contain `OOPS, a daisy`. The built-in functions I've found don't do what I want:

```
try "OOPS".write(to: path, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

replaces the entire file,

```
let outputStream = OutputStream(url: outputURL, append: false)
outputStream.write("OOPS", maxLength: 4)
```

behaves the same way, and setting `append` to `true` obviously appends my text to the end of the file. Is there an easy way to get the behavior I want?

Comment: So, given the above comment idea, you might read all bytes from the file -> modify -> write back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `FileHandle`.

```
let handle = FileHandle(forWritingTo: outputURL)
handle.seek(toFileOffset: 0)
handle.write("OOPS".data(using: .utf8))
handle.closeFile()
```

I leave it to the reader to deal with handling optionals and needing to catch errors.